# How to migrate from bower to npm

Tags: spring-boot, npm, bower, jhipster

I am working with jhipster project, in this both bower and npm are used.

Now we have to deprecate use of bower. Move to npm packages.

How can I move bower to npm with npm, not Yarn or other commands?

Comment: did you find any solution for same, you can write the answer here so it will be helpfull for others

Answer (score -1):

There are [many blog articles and even tools](https://www.google.fr/search?q=moving%20from%20bower%20to%20npm) about it as this part is not related to JHipster.
The only JHipster part is build process using gulp and bower for injecting `bower_components` into `index.html` (see `gulp/inject.js`) which relies on [main-bower-files.](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files)

Moving away from gulp to webpack is probably much more work.